# Zero Field Magnetic Susceptibility of BiSCCO

Tags: superconductivity

I have been searching in the literature, with no results, for the (Zero Field) Magnetic Susceptibility of BiSCCO, but I cannot find any article regarding that. 
Does someone have a reference that might be useful to me?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Wouldn't that (somewhat?) depend on the preparation of your samples?

Comment: Of course. My sample is actually a small (30X5X5 mm) rod, but since I cannot find anything in literature I will be gladly happy with any result that does not deal with BiSCCO whiskers.

Comment: I am simply wondering if literature values would be reproducible. I really don't know the system... maybe it is reasonably well defined.